# how to resize webpartzone in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part

Is there any way around to resize web part zones? I'm using the layout Header, Footer and 3 columns. I added 2 text filters in each column zone. But the issue  is I limited the size of the web part by specifying width as 300px but cannot decrease the size of the zone. There is lot of space in-between the web parts how can i remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the page layout using the SharePoint Designer & apply some CSS with having width in % (Percentage) to make it working for you.

Comment: Have you got it working?

Comment: No, Not yet! Tried doing this but did not see any results

div.ms-fullWidth{
 width:600px !important;
}